# Magento: multiple stores with central inventory management

Tags: magento

I have 2 stores one for wholesale and one for retail
I sell the same products on both sites
each site is on different URL, but they are in the same server.

I would like the inventory to be shared between the two sites, except this they are totally independent

for example if I have 100pcs from the same product I want the 100pcs to be available in both sites, if a buyer by 30pcs on one site, immediately only 70 will be available in both sites

Can magento do this? how?

Answer (score 0):

Stock levels are global throughout the installation. if it’s the exact same product, how could the stock level be different in different stores?

Comment: let’s say I have 2 stores, one on www.AAA.com.au and one on www.BBB.com.au
I install Magento on AAA only.
what should i do on www.BBB.com.au? if a user go to www.BBB.com.au I would like him to see a different store than the one who go to AAA.com.au. I also want him to see the URL BBB.com.au through all the pages of the store.